# Internal Error & Collection Failed while doing HW event based analysis with VTune

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, intel, intel-oneapi, intel-vtune

I have a CentOS 7 machine with Ubuntu 18.04 trying to collect hotspots for a particular application and getting error. How to fix this error.

```html
$ /opt/intel/oneapi/vtune/2022.1.0/bin64/vtune -collect hotspots -knob sampling-mode=hw -knob sampling-interval=1 -knob enable-stack-collection=true -knob stack-size=0 -mrte-mode=native -target-duration-type=veryshort -data-limit=10000 -cpu-mask=3 -finalization-mode=full -app-working-dir /local/home/vsolontsov/itto.run --app-working-dir=/local/home/vsolontsov/itto.run -- /usr/local/bin/pin -c 3 -e ./run_feed.sh
vtune: Warning: The Duration Time Estimate option is deprecated. Use the CPU Sampling Interval option on the Analysis Type configuration pane instead.
vtune: Collection failed.
vtune: Internal Error
```

After I tried the vtune-self-checker in two modes, with and without vtsspp installed.

```html
HW event-based analysis check (Intel driver)   
Example of analysis types: Microarchitecture Exploration
    Collection: Ok
    Finalization: Ok...
    Report: Fail
vtune: Error: 0x40000024 (No data) -- No data is collected.                          
Possible reasons:
 - Workload is too small. No samples are collected.
 - The application environment is not specified correctly.
 - The executable file has been stripped so cannot be profiled with algorithm analysis types.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We tried from our side and It's working fine from our side on centos 8.  As centos 7 is deprecated in the release, Intel® one API 2022.1, and will be removed in a future release. In place of centos 7 can you please use other environments then It'll work for you.
Please refer to the below link:
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/system-requirements/vtune-profiler-system...

Another Workaround: Since your OS is deprecated for the VTune 2022.1 version, we don't have other option. You can try downgrading your Vtune version or you can try on a different OS .